# how can I add video and write on it?

Tags: html, css

How do I add a video to the site and write some text on it?

Even the video I added is not displayed on the site

html:

```
<div class="p-video ">
    <video poster="image/poster.jpg" class="video " src="image/something.mp4"></video>  
    <div class="m-video">
        <div class="float-right  about">
            <image alt="logo" src="logo.png" class="image-fluid  ">
            <p class="text-justify">
                    something
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
 .p-video{
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: aqua;
     }
 .video{
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
           }
 .about{
     align-content: flex-start;
     background: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);

        }
 .m-video{
     position: relative;
        }
```

it just show my poster and m-video came under the p-video. I want it come on it!

Answer (score 0):

you should write like this for html and css

```css
.p-video{
     position: relative;
     top: 0;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: aqua;
     }
 .video{
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
           }
 .about{
     align-content: flex-start;
     background: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);

        }
 .m-video{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
        }
```

```html
<div class="p-video ">
    <video poster="image/poster.jpg" class="video" controls>
  <source src="mage/something.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>  
    <div class="m-video">
        <div class="float-right  about">
            <image alt="logo" src="logo.png" class="image-fluid  ">
            <p class="text-justify">
                    something
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why my code didn't work, but I solved it with another way.

I add the library `jquery.vidbacking`  with this css:

```
.clearfix { display:block; clear:both; float:none; }
.videokeeper { display:block; margin:0; padding:0; } 
.video-back { display:block; padding:200px 0px 0px 0px; text-align:center; }
.video-back h1 { display:block; text-align:center; color:#fff; text-shadow:2px 2px 4px #000;font-size:50px; }
.video-back p  { display:block; color:#fff; text-shadow:2px 2px 1px #000; margin:0px; padding:0px; margin-bottom:20px; }
.video-back img { width:150px; }
```

And this html:

```
<div class="videokeeper">
    <video poster="assets/poster.jpg" autoplay muted loop class="vidbacking">

        <source src="assets/varagh.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="video-back">
        <p>something</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('body').vidbacking({
            'masked': false
        });
    });
</script>
```